# Product Flavor returned as empty always

Tags: android, android-build, android-variants

In my gradle(app) file, I am setting the Product flavor and build type as shown below

```
productFlavors {

    mock {

    }

    develop {

    }

    qa {


    }
    staging {

    }
    prod {

    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

In Android studio build variants, I get the following options based on the above:

- developDebug
- developRelease
- mockDebug
- mockRelease
- prodDebug
- proddRelease
- qaDebug
- qaRelease
- stagingDebug
- stagingRelease

I have put a code in my app to print the current running Build variant as below. But the below code always print empty. Why is this so? How can I get the exact build variant inside my app? Any help is much appreciated.

```
System.out.println("Current build variant is"+BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
```

Comment: And what you expected ?

Comment: based, d on the variant selected, one of those 10 variant names

Comment: Does generated `BuildConfig` file located at `<project>/<app_module>/build/generated/source/buildConfig/<flavor>/<build_type>/<package>/BuildConfig.java` contains correct flavor name?

Answer (score 22):

You probably imported the wrong BuildConfig. Check your imports and see if it is:

```
import <your_package_name>.BuildConfig;
```

and NOT something like:

```
import android.support.v4.BuildConfig;
```

Comment: You just save probably a day of debugging for me! And it's Christmas Eve, so it has double value for me :)

Comment: You save my day!

Comment: You save my day!